# Access bean property by name

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to develop a composite that output text from a list. The list and item property to display must be set as a parameter. So I created this composite (to simplify I just kept what is essential):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:composite="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite" xmlns:bt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/tags/bt">
<composite:interface>

    <composite:attribute name="id" />
    <composite:attribute name="list" shortDescription="Output list (items itself)" />
    <composite:attribute name="listValue" shortDescription="Bean attribute to be displayed in the list" />

</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <h:panelGroup id="#{cc.attrs.id}" layout="block">
        <p:repeat var="item" value="#{cc.attrs.list}">
            <h:outputText value="#{item[cc.attrs.listValue]}" />
        </p:repeat>
    </h:panelGroup>
</composite:implementation>
</html>
```

Usage:

```
<bt:selectToDataTable id="rolesSd" list="#{aclControlBean.componentSecurity.roles}" listValue="name" />
```

componentSecurity.roles is Hibernate JPA Entity and roles is a Set.

When I load page, get this exception:

```
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet' does not have the property 'name'.
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getBeanProperty(BeanELResolver.java:568)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:229)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:139)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeValueExpression.getValue(ContextualCompositeValueExpression.java:158)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    ... 105 more
```

It seems 'var' property is not being considered when rendering view because it is trying to get property from PersistentSet instead of a item from 'roles' Set.

Any thoughts on what is going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work without a composite? Does it work with a `ui:repeat`? Put the error text in google?

Comment: Hello @Kukeltje, it doesn't work outside of composite as well. What it's strange is that same code to access bean property works in f:selectItems: <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.itemList}" var="item"
    itemValue="#{item[cc.attrs.itemKey]}"
    itemLabel="#{item[cc.attrs.itemLabel]}" />

Comment: @DavidFlorez, it's a EL declaration and yes, in theory I can get access to any property that way. It's impossible to use reflection from XHTML. Take a look: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnahx/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the problem. Gonna add my answer here to help others with same issue.

What is happening is that in JSF I can't iterate over Set, it must be a List type. So I changed from Set to List and it's now working.

Thnk you guys for your help anyway!